# What is imagecreatetruecolor used for?

Tags: php, image

According to

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php

> it creates a new true color image

but just further down is states:

> ... returns an image identifier representing a
>   black image of the specified size.

This is in some boiler plate code I use for image uploads ( to create a JPEG ) as follows:

```
private function createFinalJPEG($max, $path)
{
    $this->makeDimensions($max);
    $this->image_y = imagecreatetruecolor($this->new_width, $this->new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($this->image_y, $this->image_z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            $this->new_width, $this->new_height,
            $this->original_width, $this->original_height);
    imagejpeg($this->image_y, $path);
    imagedestroy($this->image_y);
}
```

In general do I need so many intermediary image representations to produce the end file?

Is imagecreatetruecolor simply creating a dumb black image to be used as place holder that imagecopyresampled can use?

In response an answer here is how image_z is created:

```
private function createImageZ($path)
{
    $type_creators = array(
        'image/gif' => 'imagecreatefromgif',
        'image/pjpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg',
        'image/jpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg',
        'image/png' => 'imagecreatefrompng');
    if(array_key_exists($this->fileType, $type_creators))
    {
        $this->image_z = $type_creators[$this->fileType]($path);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if you upload somefile.JPG, ImageCreateTrueColor will produce an error with the uppercase extension.  I had to convert .JPG to .jpg format to make ImageCreateTrueColor work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"So many"? There's only one. Since the canvas size cannot be changed, you must create a new canvas (image resource) to resize your image.

Now, as for what `imagecreatetruecolor` does as opposed to just `imagecreate`, you need to understand there are two main types of colour representation:

1. Indexed Colour, where the file consists of a pallette of colours, and the rest of the image resemblesa "colour-by-numbers" book. The indixes have no meaning other than referring to a colour in this index.
2. True Colour, where each pixel of the image literally specifies its colour in full.

This means that right off the bat indexed-colour images are four times smaller than true colour images (using 1 byte for a colour index rather than 4 bytes for the entire colour), however it is limited to 256 different colours, and usually one of them is reserved for transparent.

Now, since you're working in JPEG, you will want to use `imagecreatetruecolor` because JPEG compression pretty much requires this. JPEG does not support indexed images.

GIF, on the other hand, only supports indexed colours. PNG supports both (and many more obscure formats).

Comment: My image_z is actually created from multiple file types.  I added this small function into the question above.  Will this cause any issues? ( I had over-simplified to make the question simpler before )

Comment: Personally if I'm receiving an image in a format that is not known in advance, I use `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename))`